# How do I simple add/draw triangular shapes in Javascript? - This is in order to draw simple houses and ears etc

Tags: javascript, drawing

So far this is my javascript code:

Javascript (sketch.js)

```
function setup(){

  createCanvas(500,500);
  a = 5;
}

function draw(){
  background(153,153,255);

    rectMode (CENTER);
fill (153,255,153);
rect (250,500,500,250);

  ellipseMode (CENTER);
fill (255,204,255);
ellipse (50,360,50,50);
point (40,360);
point (60,360);
fill (255,204,255);
ellipse (50,365,15,10);
fill (0,0,0);
ellipse (53,365,2,2);
fill (0,0,0);
ellipse (47,365,2,2);

fill (255,204,255);
ellipse (100,360,50,50);
point (90,360);
point (110,360);
fill (255,204,255);
ellipse (100,365,15,10);
fill (0,0,0);
ellipse (103,365,2,2);
fill (0,0,0);
ellipse (97,365,2,2);

fill (255,204,255);
ellipse (150,360,50,50);
point (140,360);
point (160,360);
fill (255,204,255);
ellipse (150,365,15,10);
fill (0,0,0);
ellipse (153,365,2,2);
fill (0,0,0);
ellipse (147,365,2,2);


  fill(255,255,255);
  text("W for the Wolf to appear, B to build the house, D to break the house, R to reset",10,30);

    if (a == 6)
  {

    rectMode (CENTER);
fill (255,255,160);
rect (350,305,200,140);
fill (255,100,100);
rect (350,340,40,70);
fill (204,255,255);
rect (290,290,45,45);
fill (204,255,255);
rect (410,290,45,45);

line (125,85,100,160);
line (175,85,200,160);

    ellipseMode (CENTER);
fill (255,255,0);
ellipse (337,343,5,5);


  }
}

function keyTyped()
{
  if (key == 'r')
  {
    a = 5;
  }
  if (key == 'b')
  {
    a = 6;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a program that will simulate a portion of the 3 little pigs story. My prompt states: "Your program must have 3 pigs, a wolf, a built house and a broken house. Pushing the 'w' button will make the wolf appear (the big bad wolf should be hidden by default). Pushing 'b' will build or show the house. Pushing 'd' will show the broken house. Lastly pushing 'r' will reset the entire canvas to the default which is just having the 3 little pigs."

However, I can't seem to get a triangle on top of my house (to make a roof), I want something similar to this image below:

http://images.clipartpanda.com/house-clipart-house-outline-clipart.jpg

How do I achieve this look in the most simple way possible without altering my style of code too much?

I'd also like to add triangles to the ears of my little piggies

```
ellipseMode (CENTER);
    fill (255,204,255);
    ellipse (50,360,50,50);
    point (40,360);
    point (60,360);
    fill (255,204,255);
    ellipse (50,365,15,10);
    fill (0,0,0);
    ellipse (53,365,2,2);
    fill (0,0,0);
    ellipse (47,365,2,2);

    fill (255,204,255);
    ellipse (100,360,50,50);
    point (90,360);
    point (110,360);
    fill (255,204,255);
    ellipse (100,365,15,10);
    fill (0,0,0);
    ellipse (103,365,2,2);
    fill (0,0,0);
    ellipse (97,365,2,2);

    fill (255,204,255);
    ellipse (150,360,50,50);
    point (140,360);
    point (160,360);
    fill (255,204,255);
    ellipse (150,365,15,10);
    fill (0,0,0);
    ellipse (153,365,2,2);
    fill (0,0,0);
    ellipse (147,365,2,2);
```

As all I have right now are pink circles with little snouts and eyes; with no ears.

And if anyone can help me draw a wolf similar to this:
https://img.clipartfest.com/4ea34496a765d209ccc7b8d7b641a454_big-bad-wolf-big-bad-wolf-clip-art_236-245.jpeg

That would also be terrific, thank you!